# mysql NOW() return hosting server country date & time, but want to get Indian standard time

Tags: php, mysql

My web application & mysql DB hosted in US server, so when I want to store current date and time, it storing in **US time**, because I use **NOW()** function of mysql, but I want to store current date time in **Indian Standard time**. How can be possible in mysql or php? What would be the effective way to achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-to-set-time-zone-of-mysql

Comment: but I can't change mysql server time zone in Shared Hosting

Comment: You can change in SESSION not GLOBAL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possibilities.

1) Change mysql ini setting `time-zone` to "IST"

2) You can convert time zones using `tz_convert()`

Convert dates from one time zone to another by using somthing like this

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(Now(),'GMT','IST');
```

For this to work you have to have a valid time zone configuration, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time-zone-support.html for details.

If time zones are not set up properly you may still convert `Now()` to your local time zone if you specify the time offsets of server time zone and your desired time zone, e.g.

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(Now(),'+00:00','+08:00');
```

3) If your mysql user has the `super` privilege you can simply set the time zone at runtime using

```
SET time_zone = 'IST';
```

Further documentation can be found in the time zone manual section of mysql http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: actually this helps me CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'-07:00','+05:30')

Comment: Glad to hear that you found a solution. If you feel that my answer solved you're problem it would be good if you accept it as a valid answer, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use PHP date and timeZone functions to get current Indian timestamp?

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");

$curr_timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

Sorry if I got you wrong but please let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Hi, did this helped u?

Comment: your answer working fine but if website have so many user with many other country, then what we can do ? We should be write all `date_default_timezone_set('.....');` for all user country ?